# AWS Lambda Function cannot access other services

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda, nat, amazon-vpc

I have a problem with an AWS Lambda Function which depends upon DynamoDB and SQS to function properly. When I try to run the lambda stack, they time out when trying to connect to the SQS service. The AWS Lambda Function lies inside a VPC with the following setup:

- A VPC with four subnets
- Two subsets are public, routing their 0.0.0.0/16 traffic to an internet gateway
- A MySQL server sits in a public subnet
- The other two contain the lambdas and route their 0.0.0.0/16 traffic to a NAT which lives in one of the public subnets.
- All route tables have a 10.0.0.0/16 to local rule (is this the problem because Lambdas use private Ip's inside a VPC?)
- The main rout table is the one with the NAT, but I explicitly associated the public nets with the internet gateway routing table
- The lambdas and the mysql server share a security group which allows for inbound internal access (10.x/16) as well as unrestricted outbound traffic (0.0.0.0/16).

Traffic between lambdas and the mysql instance is no problem (except if I put the lambdas outside the VPC, then they can't access the server even if I open up all ports). Assume the code for the lambdas is also correct, as it worked before I tried to mask it in a private net. Also the lambda execution roles have been set accordingly (or do they need adjustments after moving them to a private net?).

Adding a dynamodb endpoint solved the problems with the database, but there are no VPC endpoints available for some of the other services. Following some answers I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39725326/cant-connect-dynamo-db-from-my-vpc-configured-lambda-function), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38188532/why-aws-lambda-within-vpc-can-not-send-message-to-sns), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35455281/aws-lambda-how-to-setup-a-nat-gateway-for-a-lambda-function-with-vpc-access) and in the announcements / tutorials [here](https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/aws/new-access-resources-in-a-vpc-from-your-lambda-functions/) and [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-nat-gateway.html), I am pretty sure I followed all the recommended steps.

I would be very thankful and glad for any hints where to check next, as I have currently no idea what could be the problem here.

EDIT: The function don't seem to have any internet access at all, since a toy example I checked also timed out:

```
import urllib.request

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    test = urllib.request.urlopen(url="http://www.google.de")
    return test.status
```

Comment: This is just to point readers to [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48292260/992887) which highlights that changing the incorrect `0.0.0.0/16` in various places to `0.0.0.0/0` was the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Of course the problem was sitting in front of the monitor again. Instead of routing 0.0.0.0/0 (any traffic) to the internet gateway, I had just specified 0.0.0.0/16 (traffic from machines with an 0.0.x.x ip) to the gate. Since no machines with such ip exists any traffic was blocked from entering leaving the VPC.

@John Rotenstein: Thx, though for the hint about lambdash. It seems like a very helpful tool.

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration sounds correct.

You should **test the configuration** to see whether you can access any public Internet sites, then test connecting to AWS.

You could either write a Lambda function that attempts such connections or you could use [lambdash](https://alestic.com/2015/06/aws-lambda-shell-2/) that effectively gives you a **remote shell running on Lambda**. This way, you can easily test connectivity from the command line, such as `curl`.

Comment: It seems the functions really dont have any internet access. A quick toy function i wrote also times out (see edited OP, for the function)